# Behat stopped generating regular expressions for method stubs

Tags: symfony, behat

I've started working with Behat for behavioural testing.

I managed to set behat up for my Symfony2 project, started writing scenarios. I was happy with Behat giving me method stubs with regexp to fill in that'd correspond to the steps in my scenarios.

However, after a while, Behat stopped generating regular expressions and is giving me stub methods like this:

```
/**
 * @Given I am on the page :arg1  <-- this is what I get
 */
public function iAmOnThePage($arg1)
{
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

I'd rather have it work like befor, e.g.:

```
/**
 * @Given /^I open "([^"]*)"$/ <--- I'd expect this
 */
public function iOpen($arg1, $sessionName=null)
{
    $this->getSession($sessionName)->visit($arg1);
}
```

I must have messed somtehing up as I went, but have no idea why the default behaviour changes all of a sudden.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update your version of Behat ?
In version 3 it's with the `:arg` and in v2.5 it's with the regex expressions.

If you like the old way of working you can follow the [manual](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/2.definitions.html#definition-snippets) .

> Implementing the SnippetAcceptingContext interface tells Behat that
>   your context is expecting snippets to be generated inside it. Behat
>   will generate simple pattern snippets for you, but if regular
>   expressions are your thing, Behat can generate them instead if you
>   implement Behat\Behat\Context\CustomSnippetAcceptingContext interface
>   instead and add getAcceptedSnippetType() method returning string
>   "regex":

```
public static function getAcceptedSnippetType()
{
    return 'regex';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I started off with be a lower version of Behat. Then upgraded. I ignored that fact in my head as it was just in a testing, throwaway environment and I must have run `composer update` globally. Is 2.5 the latest 'stable' version ?

Comment: @luqo33 3.0 is latest stable